# Nested Proofs and wrong vertical spacing

Tags: theorems, amsthm

I have the following problem concerning nested theorems.

Take the following:

```
\begin{theorem}
Bla
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Bla bla
%
\begin{lemma}
Bla
\end{lemma}
%
\begin{proof}[Proof of the Lemma]\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}
Bla bla
\end{proof}
%
\end{proof}
```

The idea is that I want only one `\qed` symbol, and I actually get it. But no matter how I use the `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}`(for the proof of the theorem or that of the lemma), the vertical spacing is always wrong. The next paragraph comes after a huge paragraph.
[I think this derives from the fact that the symbol still exists in a sort of a *ghost* mode]

Is there a smooth way to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which document class do you use? Do you employ a package such as either `amsthm` or `ntheorem`? Is there a material change if you issue the instruction `\raggedbottom` (in the preamble)?

Comment: I'd also like to note that it is not good mathematical practice to organize your proof like this. It makes it really hard for the reader to keep track of things. It is better to write something like: in order to proof this we need some lemmas, prove those lemmas, and the write a delayed proof of the theorem (remember you can override the name of the proof using the optional argument)

Comment: @daleif: I agree completely. Actually, my example is not completely correct in the sense that, rather than theorem/lemma, it should be theorem/claim. In that case I would say it is okay to structure the proof as I wrote.

Comment: @Kolmin in that case I would not even add a marker. A thing to consider is to use `\paragraph ` to structure the parts of your proof, it adds vertical space and leaves an inline header. It is heavily underused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to confuse your readers if the inner proof ends also the main proof.

But with `\qedhere` it's possible to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{innerproof}[1][\proofname]
  {\par\normalfont \topsep6\p@ \@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\itshape#1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces}
  {\endtrivlist\@endpefalse}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Bla
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Bla bla

\begin{lemma}
Bla
\end{lemma}

\begin{innerproof}[Proof of the Lemma]
Bla bla\qedhere
\end{innerproof}
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}
Bla
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Bla bla

\begin{lemma}
Bla
\end{lemma}

\begin{innerproof}[Proof of the Lemma]
Bla bla
\end{innerproof}

So the proof is finished.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. As I wrote in another comment above, my example is not completely correct in the sense that, rather than theorem/lemma, it should be theorem/claim. In that case I would say it is okay to structure the proof as I wrote, and I think that your answer would work super-smoothly in that context.

Comment: Sorry, one question. What should I insert in your piece of code concerning `innerproof` (in the preamble, not locally) to get a different `\qed`symbold than the one used in the environment `proof`? Thanks a lot.